# REST .htaccess causing a 500

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, restler

I am trying to set up a REST Server (Restler) in php, it works fine in MAMP

But as soon as I put it on my live server with Cent OS 6.2, it gives me a 500 error. What things would cause this ?

Here is the htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule ^$ index.php [QSA,L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
   php_flag display_errors On
</IfModule>
```

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]

^-- this line seems to be the issue.

I see this in my logs:

[Thu Jun 20 09:13:52 2013] [error] [client 5.64.252.223] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

[Thu Jun 20 09:13:52 2013] [debug] core.c(3072): [client 5.64.252.223] r->uri = /lookbunnyfind.com/go/index.php

[Thu Jun 20 09:13:52 2013] [debug] core.c(3078): [client 5.64.252.223] redirected from r->uri = /lookbunnyfind.com/go/index.php

[Thu Jun 20 09:13:52 2013] [debug] core.c(3078): [client 5.64.252.223] redirected from r->uri = /lookbunnyfind.com/go/index.php

[Thu Jun 20 09:13:52 2013] [debug] core.c(3078): [client 5.64.252.223] redirected from r->uri = /lookbunnyfind.com/go/index.php

[Thu Jun 20 09:13:52 2013] [debug] core.c(3078): [client 5.64.252.223] redirected from r->uri = /lookbunnyfind.com/go/index.php

[Thu Jun 20 09:13:52 2013] [debug] core.c(3078): [client 5.64.252.223] redirected from r->uri = /lookbunnyfind.com/go/index.php

[Thu Jun 20 09:13:52 2013] [debug] core.c(3078): [client 5.64.252.223] redirected from r->uri = /lookbunnyfind.com/go/index.php

[Thu Jun 20 09:13:52 2013] [debug] core.c(3078): [client 5.64.252.223] redirected from r->uri = /lookbunnyfind.com/go/index.php

[Thu Jun 20 09:13:52 2013] [debug] core.c(3078): [client 5.64.252.223] redirected from r->uri = /lookbunnyfind.com/go/index.php

[Thu Jun 20 09:13:52 2013] [debug] core.c(3078): [client 5.64.252.223] redirected from r->uri = /lookbunnyfind.com/go/index.php

[Thu Jun 20 09:13:52 2013] [debug] core.c(3078): [client 5.64.252.223] redirected from r->uri = /hi

[Thu Jun 20 09:13:52 2013] [debug] mod_deflate.c(602): [client 5.64.252.223] Zlib: Compressed 628 to 389 : URL /lookbunnyfind.com/go/index.php

Comment: You're redirecting index page to index page means infinite redirection causing 500 error.

Comment: the problem is an infinite redirection, do you have an index.php file in your go folder?

Comment: There could be two problems. 1( You are redirecting to index page, which is infinite 2( you do not have mod_rewrite enabled in your apache configuration.

Comment: Yes I have an index.php in my go folder, where should I put the index.php file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your .htaccess code to this:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
   # Turn mod_rewrite on
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /go/

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
   RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
   php_flag display_errors On
</IfModule
```